# how to get mobile online status of the facebook user using smack?

Tags: java, smack

I am developing Facebook chat application using smack.

1. Here I want to get online user status of both mobile user's  & website user's,
   and how can I differentiate both of them.
2. If a user send message ,how can I differentiate he is mobile user
   (or) website user?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you get it from `RosterEntry` class

```
Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Presence presence;

for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

    System.out.println(entry.getUser());
    System.out.println(presence.getType().name());
    System.out.println(presence.getStatus());//This is what you wanted 
}
```

Comment: Yes  we can get status,  but I want weather He is from mobile(messanger) or website user.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, You may use [Mobile EESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/) library.